# Indicate statistical significance with asterisks in a bar graph for two groups of data

Tags: python, plot, plotly, bar-chart

I use a grouped bar graph to indicate the comparison of two groups of data. I want to add asterisks on the top of the bars like manually drawn on the figure given in the link below. How should I do it?

Below is my code:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd
HD = pd.read_excel(r'data.xlsx')
xx = list(HD['t'])
y1 = list(HD['y1'])
y2 = list(HD['y2'])
c1 = list(HD['sd1'])
c2 = list(HD['sd2'])
fig = go.Figure(data=[
    go.Bar(name='a', x=xx, y=y1, error_y=dict(
            type='data', # value of error bar given in data coordinates
            array=c1,
            visible=True)),
         
    go.Bar(name='b', x=xx, y=y2, error_y=dict(
            type='data', # value of error bar given in data coordinates
            array=c2,
            visible=True),
        textfont_size=18,
        textfont_color='red'
        )
])
fig.update_xaxes(range = [5,70])
fig.update_yaxes(range = [0,110])

fig.update_layout(barmode='group',xaxis=dict(title='b'),yaxis=dict(title="a"))
fig.update_layout(title_text='title', title_x=0.5)

fig.write_image(r'image.png')

fig.show()
```

My desired output:

[image: My bar graph with the needed manually-drawn asterisks]

I wonder if it is possible at all with plotly. Many thanks.

Comment: What is `go`?  Also `enter image description here` is incomplete code.

Comment: Sorry for the typo. It's been corrected.

Comment: Have you considered using [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/installing/index.html#installation)?

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/67582238/13520498

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Plotly box p-value significant annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67505252/plotly-box-p-value-significant-annotation)